# Maintain Reputation After Supervisor Denigrates Me

Tags: professionalism

I had been given directions on a contract which I followed.

After 3 weeks my boss told me I failed to follow directions stating she had provided a different set of directions. She reported that to our managers upline and that I had clenched my fists and slapped my hands against my head when she related this to me as my error.

My boss is female and I am male.

I have learned that 3 other male employees had issues with the same boss and obtained transfers to other areas.  My concern is how to handle ongoing interactions with my boss while she is my supervisor.

My managers upline did not seem to be concerned about this behavior, asked for few details and basically said if she took it further it would be a he said-she said. I am most concerned, besides my reputation, about how to interact with my boss going forward.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Workplace SE. Could you format your question into paragraphs, and clarify the situation a little bit? Did your immediate supervisor ***outright lie*** to management about communicating instructions to you, as well as your reaction when she confronted you about them?

Comment: Is your question "How can I keep a lid on how I feel about this and remain professional?" or "What can I do to avoid this happening again?" (or presumably both?).

Comment: Clenched fists and a slap are mutually exclusive. Are you referring to a "facepalm" or was this something more aggressive?

Comment: What is your end goal? To survive until you find a new job? To get her removed as a manager, or to learn to work with someone you know will throw you under the bus?

Answer (score 10):

If your managers up stream stated that it would be a "he said *versus* she said" issue, you need to cover yourself by getting as much information from your supervisor regarding your tasks as you can **in writing**. ( Preferably email )

Be as nice as possible during this time, and don't draw unwanted attention your way.  This is for the short term.

Your long term answer is to either *transfer to another department or to move on to another company*.  It stinks, but it may come down to that if management isn't interested in addressing the real issue.  ( Your supervisor is a liar )

Answer (score 1):

To expound on what Mr Positive said:

**DOCUMENT EVERYTHING**

Here is how.

Whenever receiving an email from her, reply by restating what she said in the email and your comprehension of it.

"So, it is my understanding that you want 300 left handed widgets by Friday, is that correct?"

if she does not respond, follow up.  "As per my last email, it is my understanding that you want 300 left handed widgets by Friday.  If this is incorrect, please notify me ASAP.  I will proceed with delivering 300 left handed widgets by Friday unless I hear differently.

If she tries to be slick and only follow up with you verbally, as soon as you get back to your desk, send a follow up email:

"As per our conversation where you confirmed that you do indeed want 300 left handed widgets by Friday, I am taking the steps to ensure delivery of said 300 left handed widgets by Friday"  Please advise if this changes.

She will very soon get the message that you are monitoring her.  She's probably a known quantity at the company and your paper trail may be more than a little bit will received.

If you have someone upstream with whom you have a good relationship, ask if you can CC him or her on your correspondence.  Better yet if you can get someone to agree to a BCC

This is the only way to protect yourself.